# Retrofit 1.9 custom handler error

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm new to retrofit and i'm trying to implement a custom error handler to my retrofit.

I recive from server the following response :

```
[
  {
    "field": "username",
     "message": "Username \"test\" has already been taken."
  },
  {
    "field": "email",
    "message": "Email \"test@custom.ro\" has already been taken."
  }
]
```

In my error handler i do :

```
try {
      ModelError restError = (ModelError) cause.getBodyAs(ModelError.class);
    }
catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("custom", ""+ex.toString());
        }
```

My model looks like :

```
public class ModelError
{
   String message;
   String field;
}
```

But i recive :

```
 Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path
```

Then i replace the code in error handler whit :

```
 List<ModelError> restError = (List<ModelError>) cause.getBodyAs(ModelError.class);
```

And still receving the same error in log.

What i do it wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: are you using gson library to parsing json?

Comment: yes i use a gson library

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ModelResponse{
ArrayList<ModelError> modelErrorList; 
}

try {
      ModelResponse modelResponse = (ModelResponse) cause.fromJson(response, ModelResponse.class);
    }
catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("custom", ""+ex.toString());
        }
```

I believe `cause` is gson object. Hope this will help you to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get a parser error response using the following code without any needs to add a new class to handle the response:

```
List<ModelError> error = (List<ModelError>) cause.getBodyAs(new TypeToken<List<ModelError>>() {}.getType());
```

**UPDATE**

Assuming `Rest` is your Retrofit service you can get error response in this way:

```
Rest rest = ...// creating rest service
rest.requestToWebService(data, new Callback<WebServiceResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(WebServiceResponse webServiceResponse, Response response) {
              // Do success things!
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                List<ModelError> modelErrors = (List<ModelError>) error.getBodyAs(new TypeToken<List<ModelError>>() {}.getType());
            }
        });
```

Comment: I think the problem si not here. If in log on my error handler i recive "retrofit.RetrofitError: 422 Data Validation Failed."  Just in PostMan on same data i recive the json from my post. This is because i get a 422 error ? How can i see fail json from the server ?

Comment: _Callback_ is using by retrofit to deliver a result or exception in case the request was unsuccessful. Retrofit assumes that successful request is one that has a HTTP status code in range between 200 and 399(if I right remember). Anything is greater than 400 is assumed to be an error response. So Retrofit calls a _failure(RetrofitError error)_ from _Callback_ class. In this case you can use my above code(will update in a minute).

Comment: I try it your way and on failure(RetrofitError error) in  Log.d("log", "error : "+error);  => retrofit.RetrofitError: 422 Data Validation Failed.    No sign of the json from above that i recive in PostMan. Any advice?

Comment: @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                List<ModelError> modelErrors = (List<ModelError>) error.getBodyAs(new TypeToken<List<ModelError>>() {}.getType());
                for (ModelError modelError : modelErrors) {
                       Log.d("log", "error: " + modelError.message);
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

Every Json object starts with a '{' sign, every json array starts with a '[' sign.
The error you're getting is because you are trying to create a json object (i.e. Model class) from something that contains two Model classes (i.e. an array of models) try and parse the error as a list of errors rather than an object and you'll be fine..